# Is there any bound of $\Big|\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n^p\Big|\leq C_{p,N}\Big|\sum_{n=1}^Nz_n\Big|^p$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $p\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to know if there is any $C_{p,N}>0$ such that $$\Big|\sum_{n=1}^N z_n^p\Big|\leq C_{p,N}\Big|\sum_{n=1}^Nz_n\Big|^p.$$
If it exists, can it be bounded in terms of $N$, i.e. $\sup_NC_{p,N}<\infty$?

Comment: you can get bounds like that if you bound the arguments of the $z_n$ within an angle $\delta < \pi$ - your counterexample has precisely arguments $0, \pi$ so shows that one cannot do better

Comment: Fair point, then what will be the bound with the given condition of domain of $\{z_n\}$?

Comment: The bounds are of the type $|\sum_{n=1}^Nz_n| \ge c_{\delta}\sum_ {n=1}^N|z_n|=c_{\delta}N$ so then for $p \ge 1$ we get RHS $\ge c_{\delta}^pN^p$ etc for $p <1$, choosing $z_k=1$ gives LHS$=N$, RHS$=N^p$

Comment: But this is not very helpful since I want to bound LHS in terms of RHS.

Comment: so one cannot do better when $p<1$ in the sense that that the RHS is on the order of $N^p$ while the LHS can be chosen to be of the order $N$, so only the trivial inequality with $C_{p,N}=N^{1-p} \to \infty$ works

Comment: If $p \ge 1$ we have LHS $\le N \le N^{1-p}c_{\delta}^{-p}$ RHS and the bound goes to zero with $N$ if $p >1$ so we get a $C_{p, \delta}$ depending only on $p$ and the sector angle

Comment: @Conrad I see, great! Please leave an answer, I will accept yours.

Comment: Do you really want the absolute value on the outside of the sums in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comments got too long let me summarize them as an answer:

In order to have some bound of the type asked, we need the arguments $z_n$ to be in a sector of width $\delta < \pi$. The counterexample given by the OP where the arguments are $0, \pi$ shows that is the best we can do.

In the case that the arguments are in such a sector, there is a $c_{\delta}>0$ s.t $|\sum_{n=1}^N{z_n}| \ge c_{\delta}\sum_1^N|z_n|=c_{\delta}N$

(if the sector is given by $|\arg z_n| \le \frac{\delta}{2}$ then $\Re z_n =|z_n|\cos \arg z_n \ge |z_n| \cos \frac{\delta}{2}$, so $|\sum z_n| \ge \Re \sum {z_n}=\sum {\Re z_n} \ge c_{\delta} \sum {|z_n|}$, otherwise rotate by a fixed $e^{i\theta}$ to take all $z_n$ there and obviously nothing changes in the estimates above)

But now LHS is at most $N$, while obviously $c_{\delta}^pN^p \le $ RHS $ \le N^p$, so if $p \ge 1$ we get $C_{p,N}=c_{\delta}^{-p}N^{1-p} \le c_{\delta}^{-p}$, so indeed we get an inequality LHS $\le c_{\delta}^{-p}$ RHS and for $p>1$ we can have it even more precise when $N$ is large as $C_{p,N} \to 0$ fast

However if $p<1$, choosing $z_k=1$, LHS is actually $N$, so $C_{p,N}$ cannot be better than $N^{1-p}$ and that goes to infinity, so we do not get something that useful now

Answer (score 1):

No, at least for general $p\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider $p=2$ and $z_1=1,z_2=-1,z_3=1,\cdots$. Then L.H.S be $N$, while R.H.S is either $1$ or $0$ depends on $N$.